# Cloud Functions: where to keep access token for API calls

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have created a **Cloud Function** which:

1. Receives some data
2. Calls a google API to verify the data are correct

Now, to call the google API I need to authenticate first. This will give me an access token (that expires) that can be used for subsequent calls.

I'm wondering **where can I save this access token** so that other invocations of the function can "see" it and use it. I know I cannot use a "global variable" as the function may run on different machines.

The obvious solution is to write it in Realtime Database... But I don't really like it, as someone could get access to it... Does Cloud Functions provide an object or something where I can write data into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Functions are intended to be stateless, and there is no persistent storage it provides.  Also, Cloud Functions could start up many server instances to handle your functions, so you will have to find a way to share data between those instances as they come and go.

Storing your token in the Realtime Database is probably your best option.  As long as you're using [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) correctly, no one will be able to read it.