# Storing 3dparty auth access key on cloud functions (firebase)

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I am planing a project with cloud function
my functions should connect a 3d party api using authentication header ...etc

this 3dapi requests to refresh the access every hour
so i think about creating a cloud task in separate project that will keep the token.
and in my functions i will be able to get it somehow

my question is how can i do that

so i would like a 2 projects :
1 for keeping access tokens on firestore or on somewhere else
2- the functions app will be retrieve them when it want in order to make it secured

so where do I keep it and how can i retrieve those token ?  firestore ? some other service on cloud?  maybe in the same firestore that the funcstions uses?

**update**:
the way i think is

1 - create  a bucket

2- create 2 projects. - 1 for token generations , 2 fo the functions iteself

3- token generation will keep the token in bucket storage evrey 10 mintues

4- the function service will get the token from bucket evrey time

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/9eb5r7/comment/e5nki6q/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) 3rd party APIs can be stored in the firebase by following 3 ways:

> - If you truly
>   want to use firebase functions to access your keys, then yes this can
>   be done through firebase's On [call Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).

This sends a request to a function with that user's current auth state. You could then verify that the user is real and return the keys.More information on the protocol for sending this [requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference)
You can learn more about cloud firestore [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api) as:

> - Accessing Cloud Firestore from a resource-constrained environment, such as an internet of things (IoT) device, where running a complete client library is impossible.
> - Automating database administration or retrieving detailed database metadata.
>   Here a [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api-keys) on how to use and manage API for the firebase projects.

Comment: hi , talking about api app only backend , not android

Comment: can you precisely explain the issue ?..that will help me to troubleshoot

Comment: hi 
i have external api to communicate with , and ned  to make a login request, the response is a refresh token  and  I need to do a new login call every hour .

my questions is where do I keep this refresh token , 
a new project? a bucket? in the same firestore?  i
secret not good because is mean to create a new version evrey time and its expensive

is it good to split to 2 projects - 1 for keeping the token and second for achive it ?

Comment: can you look after this link : https://stackoverflow.com/q/46606026/15774176 Is it helpful?